# What is the maximum power of Return and Frustation?

Tags: pokemon-series

What is the maximum power of Return and Frustation?
How does the happiness of the pokemon affect it?

Comment: Is this to a specific generation of Pokemon? I don't remember first gen having happiness.

Comment: It was introduced in Generation 2, but from what I can tell it hasn't changed through the iterations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Return inflicts damage and has no secondary effect. The base power of
>   Return is dependent on the friendship of the user. The greater the
>   user's friendship, the greater the base power. The base power can be
>   calculated using the following formula:
>
> Base Power = Friendship / 2.5
>
> The base power of Return varies between 1 (minimum friendship) and 102
>   (maximum friendship). The base power is set to 1 if the formula
>   outputs 0.

Source: [Return](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Return_%28move%29)

> Frustration inflicts damage and has no secondary effect. The base
>   power of Frustration is dependant on the user's friendship. The lower
>   the user's friendship is, the greater the base power of Frustration.
>   The base power can be calculated using the following formula:
>
> Power = (255 - Friendship) / 2.5
>
> The power of Frustration varies between 1 (maximum friendship) and 102
>   (minimum friendship). The base power is set to 1 if the formula
>   outputs 0.

Source: [Frustration](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Frustration)

[Here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Normal_%28type%29#Moves) is a list of all the normal moves so you can get a better idea of the varying strengths of Return/Frustration. I will highlight a few of the more common normal, physical moves to give you a better perspective of how much 102 base power actually represents.

```
Move Name        Power
Explosion*       250
Self Destruct*   200
Giga Impact*     150
Double Edge*     120
Skull Bash*      100

Max Frustration  102
Max Return       102

Take Down*       90
Strength         80
Cut              50
```

* Has some sort of drawback (charge up time, recoil, death, etc)

Comment: Might consider adding other Normal (and Physical, if gen 4 or later) attack powers relative to 102 to give a nice picture of just how potent the attack is.

Comment: Good idea, I'll add some more information comparing it to other moves.

Comment: Really nice answer.